# Tkinter live matplotlib error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a GUI with live graph reading serial data working pretty good for my amateur skills, but could someone explain to me how to get rid of this error?

```
File "C:\Users\222\Desktop\V25 Live graph.py", line 200, in measure

cnt=cnt+1

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnt' referenced before assignment
```

Everything I try messes up my whole project. Thanks guys for any advice,code below.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import tkinter as tk
import time
import serial
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy  # Import numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplotlib library
from drawnow import *


arduinoData = serial.Serial('com15', 115200) #Creating our serial object named arduinoData

plt.ion()                                    #Tell matplotlib you want interactive mode to plot live data
cnt=0
style.use("ggplot")                          #ggplot...dark_background

tempF= []



# Main Tkinter application
class Application(Frame):

            # Init the variables & start measurements
        def __init__(self, master=None):
                Frame.__init__(self, master)
                root.title( "Stylibleue Dashboard")
                root.state('zoomed')       # This makes full screen on a windows machines

                self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
                self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
                self.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
                self.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)
                self.columnconfigure(3, weight=3)
                self.columnconfigure(4, weight=3)

                self.B11 = StringVar()
                self.B2 = StringVar()

                self.createWidgets()
                self.pack()
                self.measure()


            # Create display elements
        def createWidgets(self):

                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=0,padx=100,pady=200)
                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=1,padx=100)
                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=2,padx=100)
                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=3,padx=100)
                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=4,padx=100)
                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=5,padx=100)


                ttk.Button(self, text='Graph', command=self.makeFig).grid(row=2, column=5, sticky=E, pady=50)



                ttk.Separator(self,orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=1, columnspan=6, sticky="ew")


                self.temperature = Label(self, text="Bassin 2 :", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky= W ,columnspan=2)

                self.temperature = Label(self, text="DO :", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

                self.temperature = Label(self, text="TEMP :", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="nsew")



        def makeFig(self):

            plt.title('My Live Streaming Sensor Data')      #Plot the title
            plt.grid(True)                                  #Turn the grid on
            plt.ylabel('Temp F')                            #Set ylabels
            plt.plot(tempF, label='Degrees F')              #plot the temperature
            plt.legend(loc='upper left')                    #plot the legend




    # Read the incoming serial data and display it
        def measure(self):

                if(arduinoData.inWaiting()>0):

                        data = arduinoData.readline()

                        data =str(data,'utf-8')                         #removes the surrounding rubbish

                        self.B11.set(str(data))
                        self.temperature = Label(self, textvariable=self.B11, font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=2, column=4, sticky="nsew")

                        self.B2.set(str(data))
                        self.temperature = Label(self, textvariable=self.B2, font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nsew")

                        tempF.append(data)                              #Build our tempF array by appending temp readings

                        print(data)                 

        # Wait 1 second between each measurement
                self.after(1000,self.measure)

                arduinoData.flushOutput()
                arduinoData.flushInput()

                drawnow(self.makeFig)                           #Call drawnow to update our live graph
                plt.pause(.000001)                              #Pause Briefly. Important to keep drawnow from crashing
                cnt=cnt+1
                if(cnt>5000):                                   #If you have 50 or more points, delete the first one from the array
                     tempF.pop(0)                               #This allows us to just see the last 50 data points


# Create and run the GUI
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python interpreter is looking for the `cnt` variable on the local scope, which happens because of the assignment to it. Consider this example, which shows the same behaviour:

```
c = 0
def foo():
    c=c+1
foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\miniconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-c19b6d9633cf>", line 1, in <module>
    foo()
  File "<ipython-input-3-454c342b701e>", line 2, in foo
    c=c+1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
```

Now if you were to write instead

```
c=0
def foo():
    d=c+1
foo()
```

There will be no error. In order to convince your interpreter to use the global variable instead of searching for it on the local scope, use the global keyword:

```
c=0
def foo():
    global c
    c = c+1
foo()
print(c)
Out[11]: 1
```

Comment: Cheers pal solved it. Thanks for the quick response. Onward.

Comment: @LlN If this answer solved your problem, [please consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make `cnt` an instance variable of the `Application` class than to use a global variable?